# Obtener dato especifico despues de obtener un objeto con un inner.HTML

Tags: javascript, html5

He obtenido un objeto llamado valores, luego de que ejecuto la función.
pero ahora necesito, de ese objeto obtener un valor en especifico.

Quisiera poder obtener en mi variable ( let id), el value de un input, que lo tengo hidden, de name "idproducto".

Esta es mi funcion, que trabaja bien.

```
    function obtenerdato(obj){
    
                var valores = "";
                var valores = $(obj).parents("tr").find("td")[2].innerHTML;
    
                // let id= valores.algo...
                
}
```

lo que imprime mi variable valores es algo como esto:

```
<p>4820</p> <input type="hidden" name="idproducto" value="49642">
```

Como puedo obtener el value de ese input.
para este caso, la variable

```
id deberia ser igual a 49642
```

Gracias a quien pueda ayudarme.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la función [`evaluate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate) con una expresión XPath:

```js
function obtenerdato(e){
    let val = document.evaluate('parent::*/parent::*/td[position()=2]/p/input/@value'
                               , e
                               , null
                               , XPathResult.NUMBER_TYPE
                               , null
                               );
    console.log("Valor: ",val.numberValue);
}
```

```html
   <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Columna1
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>
                    <input type="hidden" name="idproducto" value="49642"/>
                </p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button onclick="obtenerdato(this)">Evalúa</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```